# Hadoop - remove newline from reducer output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, newline

My Hadoop program reads thousands of line (.log) file and  parse them.After that i write them to a file using Output.Collect() function.But after each reducer output it writes the output to newline.How can i write everything on the same line , how make can i make sure that my output file is just one line?

Reducer Class

```
 public class Reduce extends MapReduceBase
    implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
            Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        Text t2 = new Text("");
      output.collect(key, t2);
    }
  }
```

Mapper Class

```
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
                        OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, 
                        Reporter reporter) throws IOException {



    Path("xxxx");//Location of file in HDFS
InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));

                String line = value.toString();

                String bePublished="";
               String patternString = "xxxx;
               Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
               Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);


                  for(int u=0;u<48;u++){
       //Here i update my bepublished string



                  }

                 Text t2 = new Text("");
                 output.collect(new Text(bePublished), t2); 

        }
```